# What was being referred to in the Mockingjay Part 2 Epilogue?

Tags: dialogue, the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-2

The final words that Katniss Everdeen says to her newborn before the end credits of *The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2* included what I'm interested in knowing goes something like:

> ... why they came. Why they're here, and why they won't ever leave...

I wasn't certain what she was referring to, but if I have the actual words she said to her baby, that would be great. What did she say exactly and what did she mean with that?

Comment: Spoilers in the content of your question are generally okay, but please avoid them in the title. See the section on spoilers here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 7):

**Katniss was talking about her nightmares.**

Spoilers for *The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2* follow below.

---

Just before the line in question, her baby wakes up crying, which Katniss assumes to be thanks to a nightmare. I can't remember the exact dialogue, but Katniss starts to talk about the fact that she has nightmares too, and that a good way to get rid of them is to make a list of all the good things anyone has ever done. She says to treat it like a game, and although the game is getting boring after so many years (this part of the film is obviously set at least a few years in the future given the appearance of children) that there are worse games to play (i.e. the Hunger Games). She then says that she will tell her children all about her nightmares one day, including;

> ...why they came. Why they're here, and why they won't ever leave...

She's saying that she still has nightmares about the Hunger Games, the Quarter Quell and the assault on The Capitol, and that they won't ever stop.

Answer (score 1):

She says, are you having nightmares and that she has nightmares too, and that when she has nightmares she makes a list of all the good things she ever saw, and that one thy she'll tell her daughter why they came, why there here and why they won't ever go away, and that she nows it's not a good game and that there are better games to play.

Answer (score 1):

> My children, who don’t know they play on a graveyard.
>    Peeta says it will be okay. We have each other. And the book. We can make them understand in a way that will make them braver. But one day I’ll have to explain about my nightmares. Why they came. Why they won’t ever really go away.
>   I’ll tell them how I survive it. I’ll tell them that on bad mornings, it feels impossible to take pleasure in anything because I’m afraid it could be taken away. That’s when I make a list in my head of every act of goodness I’ve seen someone do. It’s like a game. Repetitive. Even a little tedious after more than twenty years.
>   But there are much worse games to play.

She's talking about her nightmares and that they're never gonna stop cause of all the things she witnessed and lived. So she makes a list on her head of the good things to keep her strong. And that is like a game. After reading the trilogy we all know there are far worse games to play.

That's the epilogue. Hope you understand it better now.